# code works only in debugger mode with break point at consol.log doesn't work otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, console.log

i have the following code which works only in debugger mode with a beak point at console.log. the array pageData is empty when it is compiled eventually the next each loop is not compiled. I am getting only 10 objects with the ajax call what if i get 100s of objects how to stop the debugger until the array is loaded. and this happens in all browsers

```
//ajax call ,
            function(responses) {
                responses.data.sort(function(a,b){
                    var aa=a.were;
                    var bb=b.were;
                    return bb-aa;
                });           
                $.each(responses.data, function (index, value) {
                       var pageData1={
                      were: value.were,
                      id: value.id,
                      name: value.name,
                      category: value.category,
                      address: value.location.street,
                      city:value.city,
                      talk: value.talki, 
                      link:value.link
                      }
                    pageData.push(pageData1);
                    });
            });
            console.log(pageData);
     $.each(pageData, function(key,value){
         table=table+"<tr><td><a href="+pageData[key].link+">"+pageData[key].name+"</a> </td><td>"+pageData[key].were+" </td><td> "+pageData[key].address+"</td><td> "+pageData[key].talk+"</td></tr>";
         });
    $("#tabledata").show();
    $("#messages").append(table);
```

edit:
    `function(responses) {
        responses.data.sort(function(a, b) {
            var aa = a.were;
            var bb = b.were;
            return bb - aa;
        });
        $.each(responses.data, function(index, value) {
            var pageData1 = {
                were: value.were,
                id: value.id,
                name: value.name,
                category: value.category,
                address: value.location.street,
                city: value.city,
                talk: value.talki, 
                link: value.link
            };
            pageData.push(pageData1);
        });
        console.log(pageData);
        $.each(pageData, function(key, value) {
            table +=
                "<tr>" +
                "<td><a href="+pageData[key].link+">"+pageData[key].name+"</a> </td>" + 
                "<td>"+pageData[key].were+" </td>" + 
                "<td> "+pageData[key].address+"</td>" + 
                "<td> "+pageData[key].talk+"</td>" +
            "</tr>";
    });
        $("#tabledata").show();
        $("#messages").append(table);
    });`

Answer (score 3):

Your `function(responses)` is only called when the ajax completes.

Javascript doesn't wait for it to complete and will run the console.log before the data is back leaving you with nothing at runtime.

In debug mode, you stop it on the console.log (before it runs) giving the async ajax call time to complete and populate the pageData variable.

All the code that relies on this data MUST come after the $.each function so that it is all call together when the data returns.

Comment: that was so helpful below is my modification to the code. Thank you @wainage